# Differential equation satisfying $f(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_0^\theta\frac{dx}{1-\cos\theta\cos x}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> Find the differential equation satisfying $$f(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_0^\theta\frac{dx}{1-\cos\theta\cos x}$$

It is solved in my reference (also in this [video](https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/the-function-fthetad-dthetaint0thetadx-1-costhetacosx-satisfies-the-differential-equation-35369)) as:
$$
f(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_0^\theta\frac{dx}{1-\cos\theta\cos x}=\frac{1}{1-\cos^2\theta}=\csc^2\theta\\
f'(\theta)=-2\csc^2\theta\cot\theta\\
f'(\theta)+2f(\theta)\cot\theta=0
$$
As per my knowledge the Leibniz rule is
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}g(\theta,x)dx=g(\theta,b(\theta))\frac{d}{d\theta}b(\theta)-g(\theta,a(\theta))\frac{d}{d\theta}a(\theta)
$$
iff $g(x,\theta)=g(x)$

So isn't it wrong to approach the problem as in my reference ?

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense. Firstly, use a letter other than $f$ to denote the integrand to avoid confusion with the original function. Secondly, it depends on two variables and so the right hand side isn't defined.

Comment: @OliverJones I don't think there is anything wrong with having two variable in the integration, thats where Leibniz rule come into picture right ?. But, here I am having trouble understanding if something is wrong in the actual question.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying.

Comment: The link doesn't work. $f(x,\theta)$ is a function of two variables; $f(\theta)$ is a function of one variable. What you wrote is nonsense.

Comment: @OliverJones I edited OP. I changed the integrand to $g$, is it well defined now ?, sorry abt that.

Comment: @OliverJones So are you suggesting the question is wrong, right ?. If I were to follow as in the attempt, the integrand must only be a function of $x$ ?

Comment: See the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \left (\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}f(\theta,x)\,dx \right) = f\big(\theta,b(\theta)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{d\theta} b(\theta) - f\big(\theta,a(\theta)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{d\theta} a(\theta) + \int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(\theta,x) \,dx$$

Comment: @OliverJones And I also fixed the video link.

Comment: @Axion004 Yes thats the Leibniz rule. When the integrand is only a function of $t$ the second term cancels out, right ?. which is what I have mentioned in OP. But, isn't it wrong to apply it in the question as in my referene, as the integrand is also a function of $\theta$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 You still have it written incorrectly in your question. Look at what Axion004 wrote.

Comment: @ss1729 Keep in mind that $\displaystyle{g(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{1-\cos \theta \cos x}}$

Comment: @OliverJones Yes. Thats my doubt is. Since $g(x,\theta)=\dfrac{1}{1-\cos\theta\cos x}$ how can the Leibniz rule is applied in this form here ?. question or the attempt is wrong right ?

Comment: @ss1729 Copy what Axion004 wrote but with $g$ in place of $f$. The answer in the video looks correct.

Comment: $\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}g(\theta,x)dx=g(\theta,b(\theta)).\frac{d}{d\theta}b(\theta)-g(\theta,a(\theta)).\frac{d}{d\theta}a(\theta)$ is wht is applied in the video, ie. the second term is cancelled in Leibniz form as in Axion004 , but in the question $g$ is also a function of $x$, then how can the attempt be right ?

Comment: @ss1729 You missed the last term. You also did not replace $f$ with $g$.

Comment: @OliverJones hanged to $g$. Last term seems to be omitted in the video, my doubt is how can it be avoided ?

Comment: @ss1729 Just work the problem one step at a time. Maybe the answer in the video is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) states
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \left (\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}g(\theta,x)\,dx \right) = g\big(\theta,b(\theta)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{d\theta} b(\theta) - g\big(\theta,a(\theta)\big)\cdot \frac{d}{d\theta} a(\theta) \color{blue}{+ \int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} g(\theta,x) \,dx}$$

where your problem is defined as

$$f(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left (\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{1-\cos\theta\cos x}\,dx\right)$$

therefore

$$g(\theta,x)=\frac{1}{1-\cos\theta\cos x},\quad a(\theta)=\theta,\quad b(\theta)=0$$

and with the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) of $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ shown inside [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518589/prove-int-0-theta-frac-sin-theta-cos-x1-cos-theta-cos-x2dx-csc2-the) we have that

\begin{align}f(\theta)&=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left (\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{1-\cos\theta\cos x}\,dx\right)
\\&=0-\frac{1}{1-\cos^2{\theta}}-\int_0^\theta\frac{\sin\theta\cos x}{(\cos\theta\cos x- 1)^2}\,dx\\&=
-\csc^2\theta+\csc^2\theta -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\theta\csc\theta\\&=
-\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\theta\csc\theta
\end{align}

so the derivation made in the video is incorrect as it is missing the third term in the Leibniz rule.

Comment: The integral can be done with the Weierstrass substitution $\displaystyle{t=\tan \frac{x}{2}}$. However, using Leibniz's rule is inefficient since the original integral can be done directly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the video is incorrect. If you do the integral directly and then differentiate, you should get

$$
f(\theta )=-\frac{\pi}{2}\csc \theta \cot \theta.
$$