Integration $\int_0^\alpha \frac{1}{1-\cos{\alpha}\cos x}dx $ in an efficient way
$$\int_0^\alpha \frac{1}{1-\cos{\alpha}\cos x}dx = \frac{A}{\sin\alpha} + B \quad (\alpha\neq 0)$$
Find $A$ and $B$
This is a high school problem.
My appraoch
I made the following substitutions and solved the problem.
$$ 1 = \cos^2x/2 + \sin^2x/2$$
$$ \cos x= \cos^2x/2 - \sin^2x/2$$
$$\tan x/2=t$$
I found $A$ as $\frac{\pi}{4}$
$B$ as $\frac{\pi}{4\sin\alpha}$
My question
But is there a more efficient way? Like Feynmann integral, or Newton Leibniz, complex number appraoch, differentiating both sides? Thank you.

Good thinking. Differentiating both sides with respect to $\alpha$ may work.

@Vasili it doesn't ( I couldn't do it) if you could write up an answer, it would be great

Reference - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3517955/1157207

@SineoftheTime please keep it elementary (I'm in highschool), the max I know is leibnitz integration

Utilize the half-angle identities
$$\cos \theta = \frac{1-\tan^2\frac {\theta}2}{1+\tan^2\frac {\theta}2}= \frac{1-\tan^2\frac {\theta}2}{\sec^2\frac {\theta}2} $$ for both $a$ and $x$ to integrate
\begin{align} \int_0^a\frac{1}{1-\cos{a}\cos x}dx
=&\int_0^a\frac{\sec^2\frac a2 \ \sec^2\frac x2}{\tan^2\frac a2+ \tan^2\frac x2}dx\\
=& \ \frac{\sec^2\frac a2}{\tan\frac a2}  \tan^{-1}\frac{\tan\frac x2}{\tan\frac a2}\bigg|_0^a=\frac\pi{2\sin a}
\end{align}

Multiplying both the numerator and denominator of the integrand by $1+\cos\alpha\cos x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\alpha \frac{1}{1-\cos \alpha \cos x} d x 
= & \int_0^\alpha \frac{1+\cos \alpha \cos x}{1-\cos ^2 \alpha \cos ^2 x} d x \\
= & \int_0^\alpha \frac{\sec ^2 x}{\sec ^2 x-\cos ^2 \alpha} d x+\cos \alpha \int_0^\alpha \frac{d(\sin x)}{1-\cos ^2 \alpha\left(1-\sin ^2 x\right)} \\
= & \int_0^{\tan\alpha} \frac{d t}{t^2+\sin ^2 \alpha}+\cos \alpha \int_0^{\sin \alpha} \frac{d s}{s^2\cos ^2 \alpha +\sin ^2 \alpha} \\
= & \frac{1}{\sin \alpha}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sin \alpha}\right)\right]_0^{\tan \alpha}+\frac{\cos \alpha}{\cos \alpha \sin \alpha}\left[\tan ^{-1}(s\cot \alpha)\right]_0^{\sin \alpha} \\
= & \frac{1}{\sin \alpha}\left[\tan ^{-1}(\sec \alpha)+\tan ^{-1}(\cos \alpha)\right] \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2 \sin \alpha}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $t=\tan x$ and $s=\sin x$.

Could you explain the 2nd step? How did you simplify after multiplying and dividing sec^2x?

@Someone take $\tan x=t$.
